# How to get current session (HttpSession) object in @Scheduled method in Spring 4.0.2?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduling, httpsession, spring-scheduled

I am using Spring 4.0.2 for my Web Application. My Web Application is about file processing. There are some statues about files like **"In Progress", "On Hold", "Completed"**. One user can complete multiple files, but only one at a time. So at a time only one file must be "In Progress" for a single user. Now, I want to check after every 15 mins whether is there any event occurred with particular file or not. If there is no event occurred, I want to change file status from "In Progress" to "On Hold". So that I tried to write Scheduler in Spring as given below.

```
@Scheduler(fixedDelay = 15*60*1000)
public void checkFrequently()
{
   // here I am doing some operation to check for any event occurred in last 15 min or not.
   // here, I need HttpSession for two purposes. 
   // 1. to get current logged in user
   // 2. to get current file for current user
}
```

Is there any possibility to get session in this method? If it is impossible, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You cannot. Session is associated with HTTP request, scheduler with time event.

Comment: ok.. but then what is alternative of this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. The scheduler is started at application launch, when there is no session, and runs in a thread separated from the servlet container.
Usually, you will persist in some form the states that you would like to make accessible by bean managed by the scheduler (being in a database, a plain file, a queue, etc...)

Comment: Could you expound on your last sentence?