# How to create session-scoped scheduler in a Spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

How can I create a scheduler that:

1. starts when session is created (or by method call from controller)
2. stops when session gets expired
3. has access to HttpSession
4. executes at some fixed interval

I've tried using [`@Scheduled`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) annotation, but it has no access to session because of reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453556/how-to-get-current-session-httpsession-object-in-scheduled-method-in-spring-4).

[Quartz Scheduler](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule) works in a similar way.

I've also tried creating session-scoped bean with [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) inside it. But when I start the timer it does not stop even when I undeploy my app.

Comment: Why? Generally you shouldn't be creating session based schedulers. Looks like you are solving something in the wrong way.

Comment: I want to check some changing data in a database inside scheduler.

Comment: And why would you need a session scoped scheduler for that.

Comment: Data is related to the user and session identifies the user.

Comment: Then just start a task upon session creation, in that task add the user info (not the session) so that it is detached from the session. Upon session removal remove the task.

Comment: I also need to send data from scheduler to controller. How will I achieve this?

Comment: Use websockets or server send events. You cannot send data to a controller.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.